# Maximum number of entries

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I have some entity, but i want to validate a maximum of X entries in db.
For example, no more than 5 categories in DB are allowed.
I try to see if some constrain validation solve my trouble, but i dont find nothing useful.
Thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to validate your entity in multiple places or do this type of validation for more than one entity class you could write a custom validation constraint to do this. It does feel a bit like overkill but it is technically the 'correct' solution. This is documented in the Symfony Manual in [How to create a Custom Validation Constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html). For example:

Constraint class:

```
<?php

namespace Your\Bundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

class MaxEntries extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'The maximum %max% %name% entries already exist.';
    public $max = 5;

    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return 'maxEntries';
    }

    public function getTargets()
    {
        return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
    }
}
```

ConstraintValidator class:

```
<?php

namespace Your\Bundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class MaxEntriesValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function validate($protocol, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        /** @var MaxEntries $constraint */

        $protocolClass = new \ReflectionClass(get_class($protocol));
        $entityName = $protocolClass->getShortName();
        // alternative to next 2 lines - you could use dql to do a select count
        $repository = $this->entityManager->getRepository('YourBundle:' . $entityName);
        $entities = $repository->findAll();

        if (count($entities) == $constraint->max)
        {
            $this->context->addViolation($constraint->message, array(
                '%max%' => $constraint->max,
                '%name%' => $entityName,
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

services.yml:

```
validator.max_entries:
    class: Bullitt\TargetNeutral\SpectatorBundle\Validator\Constraints\MaxEntriesValidator
    arguments:    [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
    tags:
        - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: maxEntries }
```

validation.yml:

```
Your\Bundle\YourEntity:
    constraints:
        - Your\Bundle\Validator\Constraints\MaxEntries:
            # You can override the default constraint attributes here
            message: "Failed! The maximum %max% %name% entries already exist."
            max: 42
```

Note, you might be able to come up with a better name than MaxEntries (I normally spend more time thinking of the most meaningful name). Also, the validator class currently contains no protection for applying it to a class that is not a doctrine entity.

Comment: Perfect, this is what i was looking for. Im not tested it yet, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to implement this yourself.  I haven't seen any such thing, but it wouldn't be difficult to do one your own.  Just add a function to check how many entries you have in the db, and call this function before you insert anything.

Something like this can be done:

```
public function newAction(){
    $isAllowed = $this->checkMaxRecords();

    if($isAllowed){
        //save to the database
    }
}

private function checkMaxRecords(){
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery(
       'SELECT c
        FROM AcmeStoreBundle:Category c'
    );

    $category = $query->getResult();

    if(count($category) >= 5){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is untested code, but something along these lines should get you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what i want to do. I was thinking directly in a validation constraint. Im not even thinking in a doctrine listener for prepersist :( Maybe a solution using callback validation ( @Assert\Callback ) ...